# Drag file to folder without opening folder

Tags: finder, ios, drag-and-drop, files-folders

Is there a way to drag files to folders without opening them (spring load)?

For example if i want to move a file from the current finder folder to one of the sidebar's folders but i don't want to see this "to" folder's content, but stay in the current folder's view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable or lengthen the spring-loading delay in System Prefs > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but then it won't move the file...

Comment: Sure it does. I toggle this a lot; all it does is prevent the spring-load, nothing else.

Comment: Oh, so i guess i have some kind of a problem, because files are not moved to folders...